# Do vb6 components need to be put in com+ for use by IIS?

Tags: iis, vb6, com+

I am supporting an ancient web application which still uses some VB6 for the data sources behind ASP classic web pages, running on IIS.

Historically we have always loaded the VB6 COM components into COM+, which was considered the best way to make them available to IIS services.  I cannot find any reliable documentation on this now - sure I have the management documentation telling me HOW but I'm not sure about WHY, what is best practice, what is required or optional etc.

Has anything changed in recent years?  Can we just register the VB6 DLLs and let IIS manage how they are used, or do they need to be put in COM+ for proper threading or pooling etc?

We have 5 IIS servers in a farm, with up to 3000 users at a time.  The VB6 data methods are accessing a number of SQL Server databases via ADODB.  The DLLs are installed and registered on each server, we don't use DCOM, but load them into a number of application groups in COM+.  Servers are Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vb6/vb6-support Microsoft only supports legacy apps to run on later Windows releases, but they no longer supports the development tools, which usually indicates that both how and why would be meaningless. Nothing changes for years. You can do what you historically do, and if it does not work, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com . As far as I know, most VB 6 programmers have switched to other technologies years ago, and the knowledge is gone.

Comment: Oh I know the Microsoft view on VB6.  When an update makes it feasible to replace with ASPX pages and/or C# data methods, I get in there and start deleting the old files as fast as I can.  The main concern I have with continuing to support the old code is the complications in deploying to prod servers, with VB COM interfaces in registry and COM+, which nearly always find a way to break if you try to patch them.